# Python cannot convert _io.TextIOWrapper to float

Tags: python, file

I read a text file which contains numbers as columns without spaces between them as

```
mediaXoriginal = open('posx_mean_no_acoplo_tf_multiple.txt', 'r')
```

and I plot my results as

```
print(mediaXoriginal.read())
```

However, I need mediaXoriginal to be a float, since I want to interpolate the data inside. If I write

```
float(mediaXoriginal)
```

I get the following error.

> float() argument must be a string or a number, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'

Can someone tell me how to convert mediaXoriginal to float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to do it as

```
with open('posx_mean_no_acoplo_tf_multiple.txt', 'r') as f2:
    data = f2.read()
print(data)
```